# Create a super user in MySQL 5.5 not working: Permission denied for root@localhost

Tags: mysql, centos, centos6, mysql5.5

Using CentOS 6, logged in to MySQL as `root`, entering the command:

```
create user 'user123' identified by 'pass123';
```

works fine. But when I try and give that user `super user privileges`  with:

```
grant all on *.* to 'user123' identified by 'pass123';
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Then

```
select * from mysql.user;
```

shows that root has Y in all columns, so should have all privileges.

I'd be very grateful if anyone could help me find why root is unable to grant privileges as I can't see why it wouldn't be working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to circumvent the grant tables in the end. See here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130296/mysql5-as-root-cant-create-database-or-do-anything-access-denied

on how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Privileges in MySQL are tied to both a 'username' *and* a 'host'.  The host can be a domain name, an IP address or 'localhost'.  Any of these can include the wildcard `%`.  If you connect from the wrong place, even with the right username and password, you will still get a permission denied error.

Each of these different users can have different access to different databases, tables, rows and commands.

It's also worth noting that '127.0.0.1' is not the same as 'localhost' as using the `mysql` client on the command line will use the socket rather than IP to connect.  If you want to use IP to connect when using the `mysql` client on the MySQL server, you can specify `-h <IP address>`.

To see all of the different 'users':

```
SELECT user,host,password FROM mysql.user;
```

Comment: -P sets the port, not the IP.

Comment: Indeed it does. No idea where -P came from.  Fixed.